# libpng16.so.16: undefined reference to `inflateReset2@ZLIB_1.2.3.4'

Tags: gcc, linker, undefined-symbol

I am building a fork of caffe (3D-caffe), on my university cluster which has a different builds of different versions of different software in `/software/software/<package>/<version-compiler>/`

When cmake executes this compilation step:

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized -O3 -DNDEBUG \
CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/caffe.cpp.o  -o caffe -rdynamic ../lib/libcaffe.so \
../lib/libproto.a /software/software/Boost/1.61.0-foss-2016a/lib/libboost_system.so \
/software/software/Boost/1.61.0-foss-2016a/lib/libboost_thread.so \
-lpthread -lglog /software/software/gflags/2.1.2-foss-2016a/lib/libgflags.so \
-lprotobuf -lpthread -lglog \
/software/software/gflags/2.1.2-foss-2016a/lib/libgflags.so \
-lprotobuf -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lrt -lsz -lz -ldl -lm -lpthread -llmdb -lleveldb -lsnappy \
-lcudart -lcurand -lcublas -lcudnn \
/software/software/OpenCV/3.1.0-foss-2016a/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.1.0 \
/software/software/OpenCV/3.1.0-foss-2016a/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1.0 \
/software/software/OpenCV/3.1.0-foss-2016a/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1.0 \
/software/software/OpenCV/3.1.0-foss-2016a/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.1.0 \
-lopenblas -Wl,-rpath,/home/p253591/3D-Caffe/build/lib:/software/software/Boost/1.61.0-foss-2016a/lib:/software/software/gflags/2.1.2-foss-2016a/lib
```

TL;DR: The essentials form is (note the `-lz` for linking to `libz`):

```
g++ ... .../caffe.cpp.o  -o caffe .../libcaffe.so .../libproto.a .../libboost_system.so ...more .so's and -lxyz's... -lz
```

It errors:

```
/software/software/libpng/1.6.23-foss-2016a/lib/libpng16.so.16: undefined reference to `inflateReset2@ZLIB_1.2.3.4'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And this seems to be correct, because when I specify the `-print-file-name=libz.so.1` option to `g++`, it prints `/lib/../lib64/libz.so.1`, which is slightly too old regarding version.

I have a newer version in `/software/software/zlib/1.2.8-foss-2016a/lib/`, but when I:

- prepend this path to `LD_LIBARY_PATH`,
- append it to the `-rpath` option, or
- add it using the `-L` option,

`g++` keeps using `/lib/../lib64/libz.so.1` as it reports using `-print-file-name`

What does work, is removing the `-lz` option and adding `/software/software/zlib/1.2.8-foss-2016a/lib/libz.so.1` explicitly as a file to include during compilation/linking. But that seems like a hack.

How can I tell `g++` to use `/software/software/zlib/1.2.8-foss-2016a/lib/libz.so.1` instead of `/lib/../lib64/libz.so.1` when fulfilling the `-lz` option? Preferably indirectly via cmake (when building caffe).

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

`ldd` states the right `.so` is used:

```
# ldd /software/software/libpng/1.6.23-foss-2016a/lib/libpng16.so.16
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff55599000)
        libz.so.1 => /software/software/zlib/1.2.8/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7875b29000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7875888000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f787566b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f78752d7000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003328800000)
```

Moreover, the symbol should be there in this libz.so.1:

```
# nm /software/software/zlib/1.2.8/lib/libz.so.1
...
0000000000008270 T inflateReset2
...
0000000000000000 A ZLIB_1.2.3.4
....
#
```

I'm assuming the `@`-notation in de `undefined symbol`-error somehow needs the A-type symbol to be there as a version check (but I could not find any documentation on this in `ld.so` man pages)

Comment: What does `readlink -f /software/software/zlib/1.2.8-foss-2016a/lib/libz.so` print?

Comment: `/software/software/zlib/1.2.8-foss-2016a/lib/libz.so.1.2.8`

Comment: Hm, adding `-L` should do the trick. Are you sure you insert it prior to `-lz`?

Comment: No, I added it after `-lz`. I'm still a bit confused, since `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also contains path first.

Comment: It seems like magic, but I cleaned up my build script, deleted everything, and the build passes :) (I did so several times, but the build script must have become correct now for some edit I've made)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you add `-L` *after* `-lz` which won't work as `-L` only affects `-l` which follow it. Also note that `-rpath` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are influencing runtime library search (and also ldd output) so they won't have much influence on compilation.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Makes sense, it comes to show that I have not been building stuff for a long time :)